# Como evitar una constraint Unique al editar un cliente?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Java con SpringBoot, he creado una constraint Unique para verificar que el ruc de un cliente sea único. Al momento de crear el cliente funciona bien, pero cuando intento editar los datos del cliente la constraint Unique implementada me impide guardar los cambios ya que me verifica el campo ruc y detecta el Ruc como repetido

La anotacion UniqueRuc es:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
@Documented
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Constraint(validatedBy = UserUniqueValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UniqueRuc {
    String message();
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

La clase UserUniqueValidator:

```
package com.bolsadeideas.springboot.app;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import com.bolsadeideas.springboot.app.models.entity.Cliente;
import com.bolsadeideas.springboot.app.service.ClienteServiceImpl;
import com.bolsadeideas.springboot.app.service.ICLienteService;

public class UserUniqueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueRuc, String> {

    @Autowired
    private ICLienteService clienteService;



    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueRuc unique) {
       unique.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String ruc, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if(clienteService!=null && clienteService.existsByRuc(ruc,Cliente.class)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

La clase UserRepository

```
package com.bolsadeideas.springboot.app;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.bolsadeideas.springboot.app.service.ClienteServiceImpl;
import com.bolsadeideas.springboot.app.service.ICLienteService;

    public class UserRepository {

        @Autowired
        ICLienteService clienteService;

        public boolean existsByRuc(String ruc, Class className) {

            clienteService.findByRuc(ruc);
        //  Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(className,"clienteRuc");
        //      criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ruc",ruc));
              if(clienteService.findByRuc(ruc.trim()).size() == 0){
                    return false;
              }
              return true;
          }

    }
```

El método que me hace la busqueda en la base de datos es:

```
@Query("select c from Cliente c where c.ruc like %?1%")
public List<Cliente> findByRuc(String term);
```

Como podría evitar la verificación de unique al momento de editar, ya que no se trata de un registro diferente sino solo de una edición

@Alex Los métodos de la clase ClienteController para crear, guardar y editar son:

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@RequestMapping(value = "/form")
public String crear(Map<String, Object> model) {
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    System.out.println("Creando cliente");
    model.put("cliente", cliente);
    model.put("titulo", "Formulario de Cliente");
    return "form";
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/form/{id}")
public String editar(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, Map<String, Object> model, RedirectAttributes flash) {
    Cliente cliente = null;

    if (id > 0) {
        cliente = clienteService.findOne(id);
        if (cliente == null) {
            flash.addFlashAttribute("error", "El id del cliente no existe en la bd!");
            return "redirect:/listar";
        }
    } else {
        flash.addFlashAttribute("error", "El id del cliente no puede ser cero!");
        return "redirect:/listar";
    }
    model.put("cliente", cliente);
    model.put("titulo", "Editar Cliente");
    return "form";
}

@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String guardar(@Valid Cliente cliente, BindingResult result, Model model,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile foto, RedirectAttributes flash, SessionStatus status) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("titulo", "Formulario de Cliente");
        return "form";
    }
    if (!foto.isEmpty()) {
        if (cliente.getId() != null && cliente.getId() > 0 && cliente.getFoto() != null
                && cliente.getFoto().length() > 0) {
            uploadFileService.delete(cliente.getFoto());
        }
        String uniqueFilename = null;
        try {
            uniqueFilename = uploadFileService.copy(foto);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Path directorioRecursos = Paths.get("src//main//resources//static//uploads");
        // String rootPath = directorioRecursos.toFile().getAbsolutePath();
        // String rootPath="C://Temp//uploads"; con windows
        flash.addFlashAttribute("info", "Has subido correctamente '" + uniqueFilename + "'");

        cliente.setFoto(uniqueFilename);
    }
    String mensajeFlash = (cliente.getId() != null) ? "Cliente editado con éxito" : "Cliente creado con éxito";
    clienteService.save(cliente);
    status.setComplete();
    flash.addFlashAttribute("success", mensajeFlash);
    return "redirect:listar";
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu controller? Estás usando un mismo endpoint para crear y editar? Quizá puedas usar dos endpoints y uno tener la anotación @Valid y la otra no.

Comment: @Alex Para crear y editar estoy usando el mismo formulario, los metodos de mi controller son:

Comment: Por eso, podrías tener 2 endpoints uno con POST para la creación y otro con PUT para la edición, que deleguen al mismo método, pero en el PUT no le pones la anotación @Valid al parámetro cliente.

Comment: disculpa a que te refieres cuando hablas de 2 endpoints?

Comment: Dos métodos en tu controller que tengan el mismo request mapping, pero uno con POST, el otro con PUT

@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String guardar(@Valid Cliente cliente, BindingResult result, Model model,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile foto, RedirectAttributes flash, SessionStatus status) {

y el otro

@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String editar(Cliente cliente, BindingResult result, Model model,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile foto, RedirectAttributes flash, SessionStatus status) {

Comment: hice lo que me recomiendas, pero solo me ingresa al método guardar cuando creo y cuando edito, no ingresa al método editar

Comment: Bueno, pero también tienes que modificar tu cliente para que haga un request POST para crear, y un request PUT para editar. Te recomiendo que leas algo sobre protocolo HTTP